# Update facts surrogate keys by new dimension with SCD2

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, data-warehouse

I have a following problem. I am changing dimension table in my data database. My new dimension table will have new key values. Because of that I need to update all historical data in my fact table and change surrogate keys to new ones. Here is the example

**Old dimension**

| id | name | value | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | Tom | 1 | 02.02.2023 | 31-12-9999 |
| 100 | Tom | 2 | 01.01.2023 | 01.02.2023 |
| 300 | Kate | 1 | 01.01.2023 | 31-12-9999 |

**Fact table**

| Date | name_id |
| --- | --- |
| 05.02.2023 | 200 |
| 05.01.2023 | 100 |
| 10.02.2023 | 300 |

**New dimension**

| id | name | value | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Tom | 1 | 02.02.2023 | 31-12-9999 |
| 1 | Tom | 2 | 01.01.2023 | 01.02.2023 |
| 3 | Kate | 1 | 01.01.2023 | 31-12-9999 |

To simplify we can assume that name is unique across all active records. So if Tom has id 100 at 05.02 then with new dimension table this surrogate key need to be changed from 100 to 1 (of course in real case it is more complex and we don't have pattern like 100 to 1, 200 to 2 ...)

**New fact**

| Date | name_id |
| --- | --- |
| 05.02.2023 | 2 |
| 05.01.2023 | 1 |
| 10.02.2023 | 3 |

How can we do it in SQL? Without SCD2 it seems to be easy, but I strugling of how to do it when I need to look also at date ranges

Comment: Are the start and end dates changing for the same name in the old and new dimensions? If they are, do you have an “event” date for each fact records?

Comment: @NickW Im this example name is a key and we can have only one active record for each name (so only one record with endate "31-12-9999"). Dates are just scd2 dates. Value is a some kind of value that is changing over time and we want to keep history of this changes

Comment: Hi - I realise that the dates are SCD2 dates. My question was when you create the new dimension, is each key going to have exactly the same set of SCD2 dates as in the old dimension or could they change? In the examples you've given they are exactly the same but I wanted to check if this would be true for all records?

Comment: @NickW Sorry, I misunderstood first comment. Yes, tables are exactly the same as in example. The only difference is id column.

Comment: Ok - so create a mapping table that contains the old and new IDs (which you get by joining on the key/name and dates) and use that in your query to update the fact table. However, if you’re not changing the key or dates then I’m wondering why you don’t just update the existing dimension records rather than creating new records and having to fix the fact table as well?

Comment: @NickW Indeed, this is what I need. I was thinking mostly about some range joins between fact, new and old dimensions but forgot that I can just use dates for simple join. Thank you really much. I need to use new keys for some more complex reasons. Speaking shortly, it's coming from one source to different databases and it needs to be compatible with all fact tables that use this dimension. Scd were not implemented on source before and each database has own implementation with diffrent ids